# Facebook4j how to get which all pages liked by User or if he is admin?

Tags: java, facebook

I am using Facebook4j for my web application i want to know if we can get what all pages like by individual user which will login in my application from Facebook Also i will want to know if he is Admin of that page or Content Creator or Manager for that particular page
I am using **Facebook4j+JSF+Spring**

Comment: Use /me/likes to get a users likes and /me/accounts to get the pages a user have a role on

Comment: Did not get it clearly any example you have?